# Webpack 5: how to allow setImmediate?

Tags: webpack

How to allow node' setImmediate in Webpack 5? The doc says I can set this property to true in the node object, but the build crashes, claiming that the configuration object that does not match the API schema.

My code is:

```js
  node: {
      global: true,
      __filename: false,
      __dirname: false
     // setImmediate: true (here commented, because it crashes otherwise)
    },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have same issue and I have solved with below steps

Please check your node_modules, and just install setimmediate from https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate if you don't have this module.

Next step, just import "setimmediate" or require("setimmediate") on top of your main js file.